# How to solve $\int f(x)g'(x)dx$ given $\int f'(x)g(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus

I want to find $\int_0^1 f(x)g'(x)dx$ in terms of $\int_0^1 f'(x)g(x)dx$, as well as the values of the functions $f, g, f', g'$ at $0$ and $1$.

I figured that $\int_0^1 f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x) - \int_0^1 f'(x)g(x)dx$, but at this point I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have done so that others can see where you've stuck. Otherwise the only answer can be just to retype the integration by parts formula, which _is_ the answer.

Comment: just to expand on already given answers. You typed the wrong "integration by parts" formula. $f(x)g(x)$ must be evaluated at $0$ and $1$. See the answer of @ellya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by integration by parts:

$\int_0^1 f(x)g'(x)\,dx=g(x)f(x)|^1_0-\int_0^1f'(x)g(x)dx$

now you are done since you the values of $f,g$ at $0,1$.

Looking at your edit, the only bit you missed out is that you evalute $f(x)g(x)$ at $1,0$ like above, i.e. $g(x)f(x)|^1_0=g(1)f(1)-g(0)f(0)$

Comment: Wait, why does that equality hold? I didn't know it held for the $g(x)f(x)|^1_0$ term like that.

Comment: yes, it is the form of integration by parts for a **definite** integral, what you have put is for an **indefinite** integral

Comment: @Sim you can see it if you apply Newton-Leibnitz formula to integration by parts formula for indefinite integral.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take the term $f(x)g(x)$ and take the difference between the endpoints, $f(1)g(1) - f(0)g(0)$ and you'll get your answer. You're basically already there.